# How can I prevent VLC to open file locations when file manager should do it?

Tags: 16.10, vlc, mate, ubuntu-mate, 17.04

When I click on any location under the "Places" menu they are opened by VLC, and it looks for media into them and reproduces files inside them.

Obviously, this is not how "Places" should work.

Since I haven't touched anything in Configuration or something like that I assume this is a bug, but I don't know how anyone can reproduce it.

It happened to me with Ubuntu MATE 16.10 and after upgrading to 17.04 I still have the same issue.

FYI, if I click on " personal folder", on my desktop, it opens file manager correctly. On the other side, if I try to open the trash (the icon on the right-bottom) it is open with VLC. Also if I click the "show in folder" option in Google Chrome after a download, it opens with VLC.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for the record, I messed up my Ubuntu and had to reinstall it, so now I don't have this problem at all